# Antlr4cs does nothing

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I'm new to Antlr. I want to use Antlr in C# and I've done all things described in https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs but when I build my Project nothing happens.

Part of my Project File:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Antlr4 Include="Model\ScriptGrammar\ScriptGrammar.g4">
    <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    <CustomToolNamespace>Model.ScriptGrammar</CustomToolNamespace>
  </Antlr4>
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Folder containing Antlr4BuildTasks.dll -->
  <Antlr4BuildTaskPath>..\..\External\Antlr</Antlr4BuildTaskPath>
  <!-- Path to the ANTLR Tool itself. -->
  <Antlr4ToolPath>..\..\External\Antlr\antlr4-csharp-4.0.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar</Antlr4ToolPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="..\..\External\Antlr\Antlr4.targets" />
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>$(ProjectDir)\copyExternals.bat</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

My test grammar file:

```
grammar ScriptGrammar;
options 
{ 
    language=CSharp_v4_5; 
} 

r : 'hello' ID ; // match keyword hello followed by an identifier
ID : [a-z]+ ; // match lower-case identifiers
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines, \r (Windows)
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the following lines from the project file:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <!-- Folder containing Antlr4BuildTasks.dll -->
     <Antlr4BuildTaskPath>..\..\External\Antlr</Antlr4BuildTaskPath>
     <!-- Path to the ANTLR Tool itself. -->
     <Antlr4ToolPath>..\..\External\Antlr\antlr4-csharp-4.0.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar</Antlr4ToolPath>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <Import Project="..\..\External\Antlr\Antlr4.targets" />
   ```
2. Use the NuGet package manager to install the Antlr4 package described here:
   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4
3. Remove the following lines from your grammar file. The language is set by the build tool.

   ```
   options 
   { 
       language=CSharp_v4_5; 
   }
   ```